WebDriverIO : Default download path is not getting changed in chrome even after updating in conf file
I configured default download directory in conf as below. But when I run test still it is getting downloaded to C:\Users\user_name\Downloads. I want test to download file in particular location
capabilities: [{

        // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
        // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
        // 5 instances get started at a time.
        maxInstances: 1,
        //
        browserName: 'chrome',
        'goog:chromeOptions': {
            args: [

                "--disable-gpu",
                "--no-sandbox",
                "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
                "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
                "--disable-extensions",
                '--no-sandbox',
                '--test-type=browser',
                '--disable-web-security',
                '--ignore-autocomplete-off-autofill',
                '--window-size=1920,1200',
                // '--headless'
                //'--proxy-server=10.229.23.252:3128'
            ],
            prefs: {

                "download.default_directory":"C:\\Users\\",
                "savefile.default_directory":"C:\\Users\\",
                "download.prompt_for_download": false,
                "download.directory_upgrade": true,

            }
        },
        acceptInsecureCerts: true
        // If outputDir is provided WebdriverIO can capture driver session logs
        // it is possible to configure which logTypes to include/exclude.
        // excludeDriverLogs: ['*'], // pass '*' to exclude all driver session logs
        // excludeDriverLogs: ['bugreport', 'server'],
    }],

I tried setting directory as below
var downloadPath = path.resolve(__dirname),//, '../TestData/Downloads/'
prefs: {
            "download.default_directory":downloadPath 

but still it is getting downloaded in C:\Users\user_name\Downloads
